# Fire JS script in observer

Tags: magento2, javascript, event-observer

How can i fire this JS with an observer every time a user is adding, updating or deleting a product from the cart ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    _paq.push(['addEcommerceItem',
        "{{sku}}",
        "{{name}}",
        "{{categoryname}}",
        {{price}},
        {{quantity}}
    ]);
    _paq.push(['trackEcommerceCartUpdate',{{totalcartvalue}} ]);
    _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
</script>
```